# Regex get text after string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to get the text after a string, that string is compound by a string and a number. I have the following string:

"Some text before and Total payment: 13214 EUR Signature:"

I want to get the "EUR", but only the EUR that is after "Total payment: xxxxx", because I can have "xxxxx EUR" in my string somewhere else.

I have tried

```
(?!<Total payment )(\d+) ([A-Z]){3,}
```

it will get what I want but from all places where appears.
I have looked at other questions but it is not what I want.

Comment: Try [`(?<=Total payment:\s*)\d+\s*[A-Z]{3,}`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dTotal+payment%3a%5cs*%29%5cd%2b%5cs*%5bA-Z%5d%7b3%2c%7d&i=Some+text+before+and+Total+payment%3a+13214+EUR+Signature%3a)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't want to use lookbehind

Comment: Will there always be exactly three characters, e.g. EUR or USD or GBP etc.?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, I want to get only the currency

Comment: @Rubyen Right, a lookbehind at the start of the pattern is not the best idea, I posted an answer featuring a capturing group.

Comment: Yeah that was it thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah it was great, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may capture the part of the string you want into a capturing group while matching the left-hand side without capturing it:

```
Dim my_rx As Regex = New Regex("Total payment:\s*\d+\s*([A-Z]{3,})")
Dim my_result As Match = my_rx.Match("Some text before and Total payment: 13214 EUR Signature:")
If my_result.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine(my_result.Groups(1).Value) ' => EUR
End If
```

See the [VB.NET demo online](https://ideone.com/XJ0TOW).

**Details**

- `Total payment:` - a literal substring (just matched to ensure correct context)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `([A-Z]{3,})` - Capturing group 1 (`m.Groups(1).Value`): 3 or more uppercase ASCII letters.

Note you may also use a *named* capturing groups: `Total payment:\s*\d+\s*(?<currency>[A-Z]{3,})` and then access the value with  `m.Groups("currency").Value`.

See the [regex demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Total+payment%3a%5cs%2A%5cd%2b%5cs%2A%28%3f%3ccurrency%3e%5bA-Z%5d%7b3%2c%7d%29&i=Some+text+before+and+Total+payment%3a+13214+EUR+Signature%3a).

Comment: yeah it is kinda ok, but I don't want to get the numbers

Comment: @Rubyen Then do not capture them. Use `"Total payment:\s*\d+\s*([A-Z]{3,})"`. See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Total+payment%3a%5cs*%5cd%2b%5cs*%28%3f%3ccurrency%3e%5bA-Z%5d%7b3%2c%7d%29&i=Some+text+before+and+Total+payment%3a+13214+EUR+Signature%3a).

Answer (score 0):

its easy you need to make your regex non-greedy. this should work

```
Total payment.*?EUR
```

adding a ? after .* forces it to only match the first match of EUR.
it will also match the literal string before .*? and .*? matches everything between the literal string and the first instance of EUR.